# Build eclipse plugins and product for different targets (with tycho)

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

I have an Eclipse feature that I want to build for an older target (4.3) and also to build it as a product but for the latest Eclipse (4.5). I hoped that profiles could help with not having to duplicate the pom files, but profiles can't contain pluginManagement tags, so I'm not sure how I should handle this.

All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Doesn't there the target platform needed to be changed? (Not that i'm sure about Tycho stuff)...

Comment: Yes, but how can I point to different target platforms in different profiles? The regular way is to do it in pluginManagement in the parent pom, but that can't be included in a profile. So according to my understanding I'd have to either: - write a separate parent pom that is almost identical; - copy the plugin configuration in each of the submodules, wrapped in a profile; - or use repositories references, which makes the build take a lot longer. So I was hoping that I overlooked another way.

Comment: I tried the last one, it works but is much slower. The other two work too, but I don't want to duplicate the pom content.